# Burninate or retag the [market] and [marketplace] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, burninate-request

I was looking on Stack Overflow today, and happened upon the [market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/market) (429) tag today. I saw that the [android-market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-market) tag has been synonymized to [google-play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play). However, [market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/market) seems to be used not only for questions about the Android Market (now Google Play) but for questions about practically anything that has the word market in it. I'm not sure if this is a better candidate for burnination or manual retagging, as there is no clear tag that all of the questions should be retagged to. It seems to be a really unclear tag, as the tag wiki even says (emphasis mine):

> Market is the place to sell your application. **Please a use specific
>   tag such as android-market,  instead of a generic one.**

The tag wiki states that the market is *the* place to sell your app. However, there are many markets, and as such I cannot infer from the tag whether the asker is referring to the Android Market/Google Play, the Apple App Store, the Amazon App Market, the stock market, or any other market known to man.

I also noticed the [marketplace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marketplace) tag, similar to [market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/market). Again, I don't know which marketplace this tag is refering to and it seems to refer to many different ones, so not exactly a candidate for all questions to be retagged to one tag.

Comment: Urgh. The replacement for the Android Market is the Google Play **Store**, but I suppose that's a different issue.

Comment: @AlE. Google is responsible for that. Even most of their own icons/logos drop the "Store".

Comment: Now [tag:market] [has been merged into](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228269/re-tag-questions-with-market-to-google-play/228271#228271) [tag:android-market]. (Huh? There are other markets!) [tag:marketplace] still exists and needs some manual cleanup.